# How to optimize query to return the highest-scoring results for each type

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

Here is my query

```sql
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'address' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'mls_address' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'state' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'county' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'city' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'zip_code' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 15)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'high_school' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT id,type,place_id,name,full_name,score FROM property_place_metas WHERE type = 'middle_junior_school' AND name RLIKE '^".$_GET['keyword']."' AND status = 'active' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Its working for me at the start, but after a while it became slow, and i want to optimize it with the same data model returned, like i want to select the whole data with a single query without using the UNION method

i cant do WHERE type In array, but it gives me like 160 rows for type high_school, and i want to select only 5 rows with the highest score

my table got like 800k records, so i want to optimise it to the utmost level

also here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE property_place_metas;` result

```
 CREATE TABLE `property_place_metas` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` enum('active','suspended') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('address','mls_address','state','county','city','zip_code','high_school','middle_junior_school') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `place_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `place_geo_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `score` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_status_index` (`status`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_type_index` (`type`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_place_id_index` (`place_id`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_place_geo_id_index` (`place_geo_id`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_name_index` (`name`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_full_name_index` (`full_name`),
  KEY `property_place_metas_score_index` (`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1406600 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

this query is used for auto complete in search bar

Comment: @WillB.
It based on the owner opinion, for the displayed data for the user. Like only 4 of this and 5 of that are needed, and there are the top 15 results for zip_codes

and the SHOW CREATE TABLE property_place_metas; is in the updated question now

Comment: Another performance improvement option, If there is a minimum character requirement for the auto-complete of 3-4 or more characters, would be to consider a [`FULLTEXT` index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for the `name` column but the criteria will be different than from `RLIKE` and would need to escape certain characters, such as `WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('abc*') IN BOOLEAN MODE` do some research on the pitfalls between the `FULLTEXT` and otherwise before deciding on this route.

Comment: Removed the Laravel related info, since the question doesn't really relate to it. Which should give more visibility to the database specific community like nbk or Bill Karwin. Updated my answer with the index optimization

Answer (score 1):

### Index Optimization

With the given criteria being used the [table indexes need to be optimized](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), as the individual indexes are not being utilized. For example `WHERE type and name and status` would benefit from a multi-column index.

```
CREATE INDEX type_status_name ON property_place_metas(`type`, `status`, `name`)
```

The order of the columns in the index plays a role on the criteria and their performance. eg `(type, status, name)` would still work with `WHERE type`, `WHERE type AND status` but not `WHERE status`, `WHERE name`, or `WHERE name AND status`.

So with a `type_status_name(type, status, name)` index, the `property_place_metas_type_index(type)` index can be removed as it would become redundant.

---

Provided you are using MySQL 8.0 and have appropriate indexes defined for the criteria, one approach to optimize the query is to utilize a CTE with the `ROW_NUMBER()` [Window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).

### CTE

```
WITH cte(id, type, place_id, name, full_name, score, rn) AS (
    SELECT 
      id, type, place_id, name, full_name, score, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
    FROM property_place_metas
    WHERE `type` IN('address', 'mls_address', 'state', 'county', 'city', 'zip_code', 'high_school', 'middle_junior_school')
    AND `status` = 'active'
    AND `name` RLIKE '^". $_GET['keyword'] ."'
)
```

The CTE will produce a singular result set with the desired `type` column groupings ordered by score, that can then be used to retrieve the top *n* values from.

### Simple Query - Parse later

For query simplicity, you can retrieve the highest limit of records of the grouping, such as the top 15 of each grouping, then iterate over the results and parse by `type`, limiting the results in your view or DTO. 
However, the original ordering and varying limits by the `type` column will not be able to be retained in the query since a `UNION` is not being used for each specific `type` value.

Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8xDcRLY2)

```
WITH cte(id, type, place_id, name, full_name, score, rn) AS (
    SELECT 
      id, type, place_id, name, full_name, score, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
    FROM property_place_metas
    WHERE `type` IN('address', 'mls_address', 'state', 'county', 'city', 'zip_code', 'high_school', 'middle_junior_school')
    AND `status` = 'active'
    AND `name` RLIKE '^". $_GET['keyword'] ."'
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score
FROM cte
WHERE cte.rn <= 15
```

### Preserve Order and Limit by `type` column

If the same order and limit by the `type` column is desired, a `UNION` would still need to be used to preserve the order and varying limits but will not have the same performance issues, since the CTE query is only being run a single time and the rest is handled by the internal query optimizer.

```
WITH cte(id, type, place_id, name, full_name, score, rn) AS (
    SELECT 
      id, type, place_id, name, full_name, score, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
    FROM property_place_metas
    WHERE `type` IN('address', 'mls_address', 'state', 'county', 'city', 'zip_code', 'high_school', 'middle_junior_school')
    AND `status` = 'active'
    AND `name` RLIKE '^". $_GET['keyword'] ."'
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 4 AND cte.type = 'address'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 4 AND cte.type = 'mls_address'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 5 AND cte.type = 'state'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 5 AND cte.type = 'county'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 5 AND cte.type = 'city'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 15 AND cte.type = 'zip_code'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 5 AND cte.type = 'high_school'
UNION
SELECT cte.id, cte.type, cte.place_id, cte.name, cte.full_name, cte.score FROM cte WHERE cte.rn <= 5 AND cte.type = 'middle_junior_school';
```

### Closing Notes

To optimize the application performance further, I suggest creating an event in MySQL that runs at specific intervals to generate the top limit of rankings for each keyword/type groupings and inserts them into a dedicated table that can be queried from. This will significantly reduce the number of records that need to be parsed at runtime and act as a pseudo cache upon subsequent calls.

Comment: the CTE query with union works, but it still take 4 to 4.5 seconds to response, which is the reason I'm trying to optimize this api, its used for auto complete, so it has to be fast as possible.

for the mean time i will try for the event you asked for and see how it goes

Thanks

Comment: But i think it would not help also, because this is used for auto complete, what ever the user is typing, i got not specific keywords to separate the top scorers into another table, he could type word "high", and it could be a school, or city of even part of an address, so i think the mysql help wont help also.

any ideas ?

Comment: Given the keywords are whole words, limiting each subgroup into the various partitioned type and name, ordered by score with appropriate indexes in a separate table would significantly reduce the scope size of the data. eg: instead of looking through active/inactive records to derive a placement, Changing the query to lookup from the already ordered table directly instead of needing a derived query with a filesort+temporary, which is the cause of the slow load times.

Comment: Outside of MySQL table/query/index optimization techniques, you may want to consider investing into setting up a legitimate search engine such as Lucene or Sphynx for these use-cases, that will automatically perform the optimizations for you.

Comment: the current approach of searching a keyword, it starts after 3 letters/digits, then i just search everything that starts with the keyword input, then suggest types with limits based on score, the problem is, if i will have another table with popular keywords, it need traffic on the site to have a legitimate data, now if i separate the popular words to another site, mostly all share the same score, so it would be like having same table with the same rows and the problems stays

Comment: did so research though for the main purpose, got some ideas about moving this sole api to another server, and use Elasticsearch or another NoSql database, it would help a lot, also got some results about cashing, but I still dont have some kind of popular/high score keywords, so it would end up cashing the whole again, so i discarded the cashing thing from my ideas.

Comment: so do you thing using NoSql such as Elasticsearch and separating the api to another server would gradely cut down the response time to less than 1 sec using the same approach of type and limit data model ?

Comment: Have you tried optimizing and rebuilding your indexes to see how that impacts performance? A search engine would not function the same way as it does in a relational database. Using a cache of user supplied keywords is not how I meant. Since the `name RLIKE` pattern is already known. In essence, in either highly optimized configuration, a full report of every possible partition of type/name-part ranking would be generated, allowing `name = 'phrase_part'` as opposed to `name RLIKE '^phrase_part'`, with no need to order by `score` at runtime.

Comment: Indeed searching with name = keyword made the response time down from 4.5 secs to 200ms, but if i'm going to use that approach, I have to make a pivot table or update the current table to have all possible phrases comes out of every record i already got, wont this duplicate the current table rows to roughly 10x at least or something depending on how many letters on the place text ?

am i getting this right or ??

Comment: That was my point in suggesting using an event to process the data to a separate dedicated table with the processed type/name-part rankings. That way you would retain the source data and the rankings table would function to serve the search suggestion references, as a pseudo-cache. There are a number of ways to accomplish doing so, each with their own benefits and drawbacks but are off-topic in regards to query optimization and would be better asked on [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ahh, okey, but it needs alot of work to have a high dependency processed keywords 
I will try Lucene and see if it manages the whole process on its current shape, if not, I will go back to this solution and think about a way to process this data in a right way

Comment: will keep you updated.
very gratefull  for your efforts, mate